# Input overlapped by keyboard on mobile

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, mobile, angular-meteor

I'm developing an app with angular-meteor and every time I focus an input which is on the bottom of the screen the keyboard overlaps it.

I tried adding this to my mobile-config.js but doesn't work:

```
App.setPreference('fullscreen', false);
App.setPreference('android-windowSoftInputMode', 'adjustResize');
```

And also this meta on my index.html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width" />
```

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Have you reached a solution for this?? i have the same setup, and dying to make it work!

Comment: Couldn't find anything yet, sz

Comment: I have made a working hacky workaround for it, if u r interested, let me know to post it here

Comment: Sure let me know

Comment: Find my answer below

Comment: Thanks. I'm not currently working on this project anymore, but I'll definetely have a look here if I have the same issue again

Answer (score 1):

So you have two options for Android (iOS handles it a bit nicer for you). In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file you will see `android:windowSoftInputMode` inside of your first `<activity>` tag. This will adjust how the keyboard interacts with the screen. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) is more information on how it works.

Comment: So I understand it should be adjustPan instead adjustResize (not sure why people recommend this one then). I tried with both anyway and doesn't work either.
On Meteor I've got on my app root mobile-config.js. This is the one that I should change. On .meteor/local/cordova-build I found config.xml (generated by the first one with the parameter). With this last one the one in platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml is generated, but I can't find on this last one any references to this parameter added on the first one

Comment: I also tried to add this property directly to the AndroidManifest.xml (I know I shouldn't edit this one, it was just a try) but the app doesn't compile

Comment: @DanielRodriguez I'm not too familiar with Meteor - yes, you should add this property directly into the AndroidManifest.xml file, though I don't know how Meteor handles that

Comment: On a normal Cordova app you have to edit the config.xml and this one generates the AndroidManifest.xml. On Meteor you don't have to edit either of this 2 ones, just the mobile-config.js, this one generates the config.xml (and this one the other one).
So editing any of this 3 files I can get any fix

Comment: this is the fix I'd like but this is using React: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580

Comment: @DanielRodriguez like I mentioned in my answer, iOS handles keyboards much nicer. The video shows an iOS device. He even mentions that changing it to "adjustResize" is your best option.

Comment: Yes, I was commenting more regarding to Android

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me almost for all situations.

This code is under the path:

```
── client
   ├── main.js

// Global variables 
let keyboardHeight = 0, originalHeight = 0;

Meteor.startup(() => {
    if(Meteor.isCordova){
        StatusBar.hide();

        // ionic plugin defaults to hide it
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);

        // Android specific events
        isAndroid = cordova.platformId == 'android';
        if(isAndroid){
            // Handle android backbutton
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButtonDown, false);

            // Using ionic-plugin-keyboard
            window.addEventListener("native.keyboardshow", onShowKeyboard, false);
            window.addEventListener("native.keyboardhide", onHideKeyboard, false);
        }
    }
};
onShowKeyboard = function(e){
    let elem = document.activeElement,      // Get the focused element
        $parent = $(elem).scrollParent();   // Get closest scrollable ancestor (jQuery UI)

    // If there is no scrollable parent, no need to continue processing
    if($parent.length == 0){
        return;
    }

    // Check if the keyborad type has changed (i.e. from text to number)
    if(keyboardHeight != e.keyboardHeight){
        keyboardHeight = e.keyboardHeight;
    }

    // Don't resize if the original height hasn't been reset by onHideKeyboard()
    if(originalHeight == 0){
        originalHeight = $parent.height();
    }

    // Subtract keyboard height from parent height + accessory bar height
    // Add some class to the parent, to be able to get it back to normal state onHideKeyboard()
    $parent.height(originalHeight - keyboardHeight + 50).addClass('adjusted');

    // Give the keyboard time to show
    setTimeout(function() {     
        // Scroll to active element
        document.activeElement.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth", // or "auto" or "instant"
            block: "center"     // or "start" or "end"
        });
    }, 100);

    // Unbind DOM object from HTML for garbage collection
    elem = null;
    $parent.prevObject = null; // To avoid memory leak (for any jQuery DOM object)
    $parent = null;
};
onHideKeyboard = function(e){
    let s = $('.adjusted').attr('style');
    s = s.replace(/height.*;/, '');
    $('.adjusted').attr('style', s).removeClass('adjusted');
    keyboardHeight = 0;
    originalHeight = 0;
};
```